# Session-ID and Browser-Caching => Are Browser intelligent enough to strip of SessID?

Tags: caching

I have a big question: Please see the example link below. My application currently appends to all "resources/links" a Session ID. I more or less stumbled upon this by accident looking in the Firefox Cache:

```
http://localhost:8080/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css;jsessionid=A8483FBF3BB6DDA499E06210BE0D612C
```

My big question is, will a URL like the URL above lead to the fact, that any caching Header (I use Cache-Control with several Years) will become more or less useless, as the session ID will make every request unique?

(==>What I mean is, that a new sessionID is assigend after 30 Minutes. And caching will most likely then only be effective within this period. After this period a new Session ID will be generated, indirectly invalidating all the cached content on the client side, that has the SessionID in its url  = the url changes as it now has a new sessionID.)

=> Are the browsers as intelligent to find out that the resource to cache is:

```
http://localhost:8080/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css
```

and not:

```
http://localhost:8080/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css;jsessionid=A8483FBF3BB6DDA499E06210BE0D612C
```

Or will a sessionId in url lead to the fact that caching is more or less disabled in the browser?

Thank you very much!
jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a question of if browsers are smart enough. The [W3 standard for HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) states that different URLs should be cached separately. So browsers are correct in observing the full URL, including GET arguments such as a session ID in their caching.

You should not be appending the session ID to *anything* that is static (such as your style-sheet).

Comment: hello ben, thanks for your answer and the link. I googled, but the W3 document didnt show up. Its a great document explaining everthing, exactly what I was looking for. So thanks for your answer.

Comment: I recently answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674493/back-button-browser-behavior/1674525#1674525 so I had the link handy :D

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - the browser is not smart enough, and a changing URL will pretty efficiently negate caching.

Why do you have the session ID there in the first place? If the resource is not session-dependant, then remove the session ID from the URL and that will fix your problem. If the resource is session-dependant, then you already have all you need, because one session should not use the resource from another session.